# How to import all txt files in two different folders, combine corresponding files into single file and write separate file in R?

Tags: r

I have daily temperature and relative humidity (in fraction) data for 35 years from 400 stations. The data are stored in different files for each parameter and each station. Temperature data are stored on file name like t264797.txt, t264800.txt, t264803.txt ...... and relative humidity data stored on a file name like r264797.txt, r264800.txt, r264803.txt ....... The numeric part of the file name is latitude and longitude of that station.

The format of the temperature data is

```
19790101
23.985,6.152
25.539,8.900
26.492,10.806
.
.
```

here first row is starting date and followed by daily maximum and minimum temperature data separated by ','.

The format of the relative humidity data is

```
19790101
0.416
0.323
0.394
.
.
```

Here also first row is starting date and followed by daily relative humidity data in fraction. All data have same starting date and all for 35 years.

Now to give input for my hydrological model i need one file for each stations containing both temperature and relative humidity (in percentage) data in same file and data should be separated by space. For example data should be in this format

```
23.985 6.152 41.6
25.539 8.9 32.3
26.492 10.806 39.4
.
.
```

I am new to R and reading other posts i figured out that i can do it for single station by running following syntaxes

```
temp <- read.csv("D:/krb/wegen/swatintdata/temp/t264797.txt", header=FALSE, skip=1)
huf <- read.table("D:/krb/wegen/swatintdata/rh/r264797.txt", header=TRUE)
hup <-huf*100
dewfile <- cbind(temp,hup)
write.table(dewfile,"D:/krb/wegen/swatintdata/dew/d264797.txt", row.names=F, col.name=F )
```

This worked fine for single stations. Now i want to write a script that combines each station temperature and relative humidity data in separate file and write a one file for each station for all 400 station :). The file name of the combined data should be similar like in syntax above ie d264797.txt, d264800.txt, d264803.txt....

Any helps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all your files in the same folder, get all the file names as an object with

```
all <- list.files(pattern="\\.txt", full=T)
```

Then read the files as a list with

```
lapply(all, read.table, header=T, sep="\t")
```

This would allow you to manipulate all the data within the R environment, including binding and saving them out.

Here's a simplified example to read two iris data-set and bind them together with `plyr::ldply` command:

```
write.table(iris, "iris01.txt", sep="\t", row.names=F)
write.table(iris, "iris02.txt", sep="\t", row.names=F)
all <- list.files(pattern="\\.txt", full=T)
ldply(all, read.table, header=T, sep="\t")
```

Comment: Thanks Adam for your time and effort for reply. But unfortunately as i am new to R, i didnt get your point. Sorry for that. Can you please make more clear with my data? Thank you again in advance :)

Comment: @Amrit, I'd put up a short guide at https://minerva79.github.io/Reading-multiple-files-in-R/ Let me know if you have specific issues.